# tsoa-swagger: file parameter is always undefined in upload

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, multer, tsoa

I have a problem with Tsoa nodejs File upload

I wrote the method based on the [tsoa documentation](https://tsoa-community.github.io/docs/file-upload.html) but the output varible is always undefined

This is my method

[image]

```js
  @Post('/uploadNewExporterTemplate')
  public async uploadNewExporterTemplate(
    @Query() templateName: string,
    @Query() unit: string,
    @Query() testWith: string,
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
  )  {

    const mul = multer()

    
    console.log(file,unit,testWith);
    
    return {stat:"Ok",ss:templateName}
  }
```

And this is the swagger result

[image]

and finally this the debug result

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the undefined variable?

Comment: the variable `file`  'https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9pdK.png'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why but according to provided screenshot of Swagger UI, your `file` field is in `Request body` section, but the rest of the fields are in `Parameters` section. As far as I know, all fields should be in one section called `Request body` or `Parameters`.

I suggest you try changing `Query()` to `FormField()` accordingly to [tsoa docs](https://tsoa-community.github.io/docs/file-upload.html#using-the-uploadedfile-uploadedfiles-decorator).

If above does not help, I have a few suggestions:

1. Check what's inside generated routes file. There should be some multer logic added by tsoa.
2. Compare your generated `swagger.json` with [the one provided](https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json) in [the Swagger example](https://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/uploadFile).
3. Try running the request outside Swagger UI (e.g.: Postman) or use DevTools to check what is Swagger UI does under the hood (Network tab, check the requests).

Comment: Thank you  dear, I solved the problem by adding a custom middleware to receive and prepare file from request with tag `@UploadedFile()` to show input file in swagger interface.
So I think the problem is the default tsoa middleware...
I created an issue in TSOA repository  with the bug `https://github.com/lukeautry/tsoa/issues/1099`